# VB Loading photos on splash screen

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, basic

I'm trying to load all photos into buttons on my system. I manage to make it load after login, but the images takes time to load after login. So, I want to make it load after splash screen.

```
Private Sub picture()
    Dim filePath As String

    filePath = "C:\Users\ress\source\repos\restaurant 2019\text\food_image.txt"
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

    fAdmin.btnFood0.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(0))
    fMain.btnFood0.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(0))
    fAdmin.btnFood1.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(1))
    fMain.btnFood1.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(1))
    fAdmin.btnFood2.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(2))
    fMain.btnFood2.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(2))
    fAdmin.btnFood3.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(3))
    fMain.btnFood3.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(3))
    fAdmin.btnFood4.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(4))
    fMain.btnFood4.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(4))
    fAdmin.BtnFood5.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(5))
    fMain.BtnFood5.Image = Image.FromFile(lines(5))
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. And what issue are you having?

Comment: how to load the photos on splash screen. I don't know where to put the code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can use Form-shown event to load the photos.

Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        picture()

    End Sub
```